# How can I permanently disable a button after completing a form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm currently in the process of creating a reservation page for our company. What I would like to do is have it to where when the user clicks the **Reserve Now Button** a form pops up for them to complete. After the user completes the form the reserve button is disabled permanently to everyone accessing the site. How can I accomplish this? I am not very well versed in java script or php. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
           <table class="table table-striped">
             <tr>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary ">RESERVE NOW</a></td>
             </tr>
           </table>
           <form>
             First name:<br>
             <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
             <br>
             Last name:<br>
             <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
             <br><br>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
           </form>  
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

I have mocked up an example that can be found here:
    https://jsfiddle.net/rman215/gw2m53w9/1/

Comment: the disabled attribute: `<input type="submit" value="submit" disabled>`

Comment: You will need to set a value in your database to keep track of that reservation being used already.

Comment: if the reserve now refers to a particular item/product, you would need to store the status in a database.  when a user reserves the item, update the database for the item by changing it to a reserved status.  the button is only enabled when the item status is free / unreserved.

Comment: This also doesn't address how to handle concurrency.  Two people are viewing the form.  One clicks reserve now.  The other person's button isn't going to get disabled.  You'll need to check the item status before updating it to reserved, and let the user know if someone else beat them to the reservation.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the solution is moving towards AJAX, if there's a need to disable the button in everyone's browser in real time. (In any case, something needs to be stored in the backend for permanency.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you you want to provide ability ti reserve something, but only for 1 person, right?

So, you can store flag in database (for example in `disabled_at` [timestamp, default = null] column). When somebody click on button and call processing page (via ajax or simple redirect) set flag `disabled_at` value `NOW()`. And each time on processing page is `disabled_at IS NULL`. If yes - save first and last name to database.

On page with form need to add attribute `disabled` to submit button if `disabled_at IS NOT NULL`

**EDIT:**

**disable.php**

```
<?php

function reserveItem($name = null, $value = null)
{
    $name .= '.reserved';
    $value = $value ? $value : 1;
    return file_put_contents($name, $value);
}

function isDisabled($name = null)
{
    return file_exists($name . '.reserved');
}

$disabled = isDisabled('item1');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
    $lastName = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '';
    if (!$disabled) {
        reserveItem('item1', $name . $lastName);
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
           <table class="table table-striped">
             <tr>
                <td>Product</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary ">RESERVE NOW</a></td>
             </tr>
           </table>
           <form method="post" action="disable.php">
             First name:<br>
             <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
             <br>
             Last name:<br>
             <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
             <br><br>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit" <?= $disabled ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>>
           </form>  
       </div>
     </div>
   </div> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

**Note:** code written in editor only and not tested.

Comment: I don't have a database connected to the site. Can this be accomplished without the using a database? If not, do you have any suggestion of tying  a database to my working site. I am hosting with iPage and I don't know if they support databases.

Comment: You may store `disabled flag` value in file. Logic the same, for example you may create file `item_name.reserved` when somebody reserve it. And on processing page you will check is file exists (if not - available to reservation).

Comment: What you are trying to do requires persistence in a database, you'll have to access your hosting control panel. Your hosting support MySql Databases, depending on the control panel provided probably there is an option to use PHPMyAdmin to manage your database. You can look in the documentation provided by your hosting.

Comment: Stafox could you please provide example code of how this would be done. I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Yes I can, but a little bit later, I should get access to pc. Now I write from my iphone

Comment: @rman215 see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

give id to submit button and on click of submit call this function

```
function disableButton() {
     $("#idOfButton").attr("disabled","disabled")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After form submit you will get the success response. After getting success just disable the **Reserve Now Button** using this code :

If you are using ajax to submit form then you need to do that :
suppose **Reserve Now Button** id : reserve_btn_id

```
$.ajax({
  // your code....
}).done(function() {
  $("#reserve_btn_id").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `JavaScript` is executed every time a client loads the page, you cannot insert `JavaScript` code to block the button.
I suggest you to use a simple `MySQL` database, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Items(
   ItemID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Description VARCHAR(255),
   IsReserved TINYINT(1) //this works like a boolean        
);
```

So that your page will have a select of all items, something like this:

`SELECT * FROM Items ORDER BY ItemID`

And then you will print them with something like this:

```
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "mydatabase";
$connection = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Items ORDER BY ItemID");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   echo("<form action=\"mypage.php\" method=\"post\">");
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      echo("input name=\"id\" type=\"hidden\" value=" . $row['ItemID'] . ">"); //this input type hidden isn't shown on the page but we use it to store the id of the item so that we can retrieve it on the PHP page on submit
      echo("ID: " . $row['ItemID']);
      echo("Description: " . $row['Description']);
      if ($row['IsReserved'] == 1){
         echo("<button class=\"mybutton\" type=\"submit\" disabled>Reserve</button>");
      }
      else{
         echo("<button class=\"mybutton\" type=\"submit\">Reserve</button>");
      }
   }
   echo("</form>");
}
else{
   echo("No data");
}
```

Then to update the status of an item that is reserved, just update the status when the form has been submitted to the other `PHP` page, you will have something like this:

```
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "mydatabase";
$connection = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

$id = (int) $_POST['id']; // here you get the id of the hidden input

 // $data = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ItemID = $id");

/* $data now contains all info stored about the item, you can use it if you
   need to insert those info in another table, etc. */ 

// UPDATING STATUS
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE Items SET IsReserved = 1 WHERE ItemID = $id");

mysqli_close($connection);
```

So this is it, basically, I hope it helps you with your project :)

I leave you [this guide](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) on how to handle Forms & their data with `PHP`.